# tkinter optionmenu keyerror on first 2 options

Tags: python, tkinter, trace, optionmenu

I have 2 optionmenus. we will call optionmenu1 `plan_time`, and optionmenu2 `week_options`.

The first option menu (`plan_time`) sets a number of weeks. when saved, it updates the second optionmenu (`week_options`) by running this function which destroys week_options, and rebuilds it.

The code used to write the new copy of `week_options` is the same as the code used to write the first copy of `week_options`.

There is a trace on `week_clicked` (`week_options`) which works fine. UNTIL the new number of weeks is saved and the widget is destroyed and redrawn. Then for some reason, the top 2 options of my newly created list do not work.

```
currentweek = 4  # this is grabbed from config.ini but will just place a number for now.

def build_optionmenu():
    week_options.destroy()
    week_optionlist = {'Current Week':currentweek}
    add_optionlist = {"Week " + str(i):i for i in range(1,(plan_time_optionlist[plan_time_clicked.get()])+1)}
    week_optionlist.update(add_optionlist)
    week_clicked.set(currentweek)
    week_options = tk.OptionMenu(frame_settings_section2, week_clicked, *week_optionlist.keys())
    week_options.pack()

    print(week_optionlist)

plan_time_optionlist = {'Continuous':1}
add_optionlist = {str(i) + " Weeks":i for i in range(2,17)}
plan_time_optionlist.update(add_optionlist)
plan_time_clicked = StringVar()
plan_time_clicked.set(df_duration.get() + " Weeks")
plan_time_options = tk.OptionMenu(frame_settings_section2, plan_time_clicked, *plan_time_optionlist.keys())
plan_time_options.pack()
tk.Button(frame_settings_section2, text="<save>", command=update_optionmenus).pack()
```

I printed the list to see if it looks funny, but it looks how it should.

```
{'Current Week': 4, 'Week 1': 1, 'Week 2': 2, 'Week 3': 3, 'Week 4': 4, 'Week 5': 5,...}
```

So I don't understand why the first 2 options, "current week" and "Week 1"
give `KeyError: 'Current Week'`
and `KeyError: 'Week 1'`
when I click them from the re-created dropdown menu.

Comment: i have done nothing to the function, and now week 1 works. any ideas what this might be  LOL

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what the problem was, other than its related to the traced stringvar being used by the optionmenu. when the optionmenu is deleted the trace acts funny and not all of the the items in the second option menu work.

**HERE IS A WORKING EXAMPLE**

copy and paste this into a tkinter window

build optionmenu2 explained:

- try: delete optionmenu2 and trace associated with it.
- if optionmenu1 is 'continuous', then build a label instead of a pointless optionmenu that has just 1 option.
- if the current week (since program started) is greater than the number of weeks selected, it will display error(N) at the top of the optionmenu to let the user know we are currently in a higher week than selected.
- builds optionmenu2 and sets default to either current week, or the last week chosen in optionmenu1, whichever is greater.

load_week is called everytime an option is selected in optionmenu2
I used the option selected to change what gets loaded.

```
    df_duration = StringVar()
    optionlist2_clicked = StringVar()
    df_duration.set('10')
    sys_weeks_growing = '4'
    
    label = tk.Label(self, text='how many weeks would you like the program to run')
    label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    
    def build_optionmenu2(*args):
        global optionmenu2, optionlist2
        try:
            optionmenu2.destroy()
            optionlist2_clicked.trace_vdelete('w', optionlist2_clicked.trace_week)
        except (NameError, AttributeError, KeyError):
            pass
        finally:
            if optionlist1[optionlist1_clicked.get()] == 1:
                tk.Label(self, text='Continuous:').pack(padx=10, pady=10)
                optionlist2_clicked.trace_week = optionlist2_clicked.trace_add('write', load_week)
                optionlist2_clicked.set('Week 1')
            elif int(optionlist1[optionlist1_clicked.get()]) >= 1:
                if int(optionlist1[optionlist1_clicked.get()]) >= int(sys_weeks_growing):
                    optionlist2 = {('Current(' + str(sys_weeks_growing) + ')'): sys_weeks_growing}
                else:
                    optionlist2 = {('Caution(' + str(sys_weeks_growing) + ')'): 1}
                new_optionlist = {"Week " + str(i): i for i in
                                  range(1, (optionlist1[optionlist1_clicked.get()]) + 1)}
                optionlist2.update(new_optionlist)
                optionmenu2 = tk.OptionMenu(self, optionlist2_clicked, *optionlist2.keys())
                optionmenu2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
                optionlist2_clicked.trace_week = optionlist2_clicked.trace_add('write', load_week)
                if int(optionlist1[optionlist1_clicked.get()]) >= int(sys_weeks_growing):
                    optionlist2_clicked.set('Week ' + str(sys_weeks_growing))
                else:
                    optionlist2_clicked.set('Week ' + str(optionlist1[optionlist1_clicked.get()]))
                 
    def load_week(*args):
        print('data loaded...')
    
    optionlist1 = {'Continuous': 1}
    add_optionlist = {str(i) + " Weeks": i for i in range(2, 17)}
    optionlist1.update(add_optionlist)
    optionlist1_clicked = StringVar()
    optionlist1_clicked.set(df_duration.get() + " Weeks")
    optionmenu1 = tk.OptionMenu(self, optionlist1_clicked, *optionlist1.keys())
    optionmenu1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    optionlist1_clicked.trace_add('write', build_optionmenu2)   
    
    label = tk.Label(self, text='which week would you like to display').pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    
    build_optionmenu2()
        
    label = tk.Label(self, text='place widgets here that update when a week is selected from option menu 2')
    label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')
```